# I have a json object with array object inside, how to access array object and if same product display only once and sum the price

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb

This is my json

```
let obj = [{
"_id" : "WER12345",
"date" : "2022-07-24",
"totalproduct" : 6,
"productlist" : [
    {
        "product" : "iphone 13",
        "price" : 1000
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 11",
        "price" : 600
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 13",
        "price" : 1000
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    }
] },{

"_id" : "WER98763",
"date" : "2022-07-24",
"totalproduct" : 4,
"productlist" : [
    {
        "product" : "iphone 13",
        "price" : 1000
    },
    
    {
        "product" : "iphone 11",
        "price" : 600
    },
   
    {
        "product" : "iphone 11",
        "price" : 600
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    }
]}]
```

how to get this from above json in Nodejs and send to frontend reactjs
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrTGG.png)

[{
"_id" : "WER12345",
"date" : "2022-07-24",
"totalproduct" : 6,
"productlist" : [
{
"product" : "iphone 13",
"price" : 2000
},
{
"product" : "iphone 12",
"price" : 2400
},
{
"product" : "iphone 11",
"price" : 600
}

```
] },{

"_id" : "WER98763",
"date" : "2022-07-24",
"totalproduct" : 4,
"productlist" : [
    {
        "product" : "iphone 13",
        "price" : 1000
    },
    
    {
        "product" : "iphone 11",
        "price" : 1200
    },

    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    }
]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to group productlist by product property.

Here is code for the same.

```
const jsonResponse = {
    _id: 'WER12345',
    date: '2022-07-24',
    totalproduct: 4,
    productlist: [
        { product: 'iphone 13', price: 1000 },
        { product: 'iphone 12', price: 800 },
        { product: 'iphone 11', price: 600 },
        { product: 'iphone 12', price: 800 },
        { product: 'iphone 13', price: 1000 },
        { product: 'iphone 12', price: 800 },
    ],
};
// Below variable has value in asked format
const jsonResAfterFormatting = transformResponse(jsonResponse);
function groupProductsByProduct(productList) {
    const products = {};
    productList.forEach(productDetails => {
        if (productDetails.product in products) {
            products[productDetails.product] += productDetails.price;
        } else {
            products[productDetails.product] = productDetails.price;
        }
    });
    const groupedProductList = [];
    for (let product in products) {
        const price = products[product];
        const productDetails = {
            product,
            price,
        };
        groupedProductList.push(productDetails);
    }
    return groupedProductList;
}

function transformResponse(jsonResponse) {
    const groupedProductList = groupProductsByProduct(jsonResponse.productlist);
    // if "jsonResponse" is a type of array
    
    /*
    const result = []
    jsonResponse.forEach((productElement)=>{
        let groupedProductList = groupProductsByProduct(jsonResponse.productlist);
        result.push({ ...productElement, productlist: groupedProductList })
    }) 
    return res */
    return { ...jsonResponse, productlist: groupedProductList };
}
```

Comment: This one is working fine, how if we have data like below 
const jsonResponse = [{
            _id: 'WER12345',
            date: '2022-07-24',
            totalproduct: 4,
            productlist: [ { product: 'iphone 13', price: 1000 },
                { product: 'iphone 12', price: 800 },
                { product: 'iphone 12', price: 800 },
            ], },{
            _id: 'WER78539',
            date: '2022-07-24',
            totalproduct: 4,
            productlist: [  { product: 'iphone 13', price: 1000 }, { product: 'iphone 11', price: 600], }];

Comment: Hi @kick, I have added comments for that as well. Please check my comments in function "transformResponse" of solution code provided by me. If you still have any kind of question, feel free to ask

Answer (score -1):

We can take an temp object and with key as product name and value as price. Then we can iterate through prodcuctlist and add the prices of respective product in temp object.

```
let obj = {
"_id" : "WER12345",
"date" : "2022-07-24",
"totalproduct" : 4,
"productlist" : [
    {
        "product" : "iphone 13",
        "price" : 1000
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 11",
        "price" : 600
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 13",
        "price" : 1000
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    }
]
}


let products =obj.productlist;
let temp_obj = {}
for(let product of products){
    if(temp_obj[product.product]){
        temp_obj[product.product] =  temp_obj[product.product]  + product.price;
    }else{
         temp_obj[product.product] = product.price;
    }
}

let keys = Object.keys(temp_obj);
let values = Object.values(temp_obj);
let productList = []
for(let i=0;i<keys.length;i++){
    let obj = {}
    obj['product'] = keys[i];
    obj['price'] = values[i];
    productList.push(obj);
}

obj.productlist = productList;

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to achieve this.

```js
let productlist = [
    {
        "product" : "iphone 13",
        "price" : 1000
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 11",
        "price" : 600
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 13",
        "price" : 1000
    },
    {
        "product" : "iphone 12",
        "price" : 800
    }
];

// create a map of {$product: $accumulatePrice} based on the data in productlist array
let groupByProduct = productlist.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if(acc[curr.product]) {
        acc[curr.product] += curr.price;
    } else {
        acc[curr.product] = curr.price;
    }
    return acc;
},{});

// convert the groupByProduct map into an array of object(your expected format)
let resList = Object.keys(groupByProduct).map(key => {
    return{
        "product" : key,
        "price" : groupByProduct[key]
    };
});

console.log(resList);
```